# Can't fill some cells of tablewidget. PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm programming a simple csv handler that will just look at two columns using python 3.7.2 and pyqt5. It will have a desired number of rows and all of them needs to be filled for my program to work. But when I run my loops only 11 out of 20 cells get filled. When I decrease the row count to 10 this ratio is 6/10 and for 6 this is 4/6. I can't find why this occurs.

Here is the loop that sets the headers firstly.

```
x = 0
    while x<total_rows:
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(x, item)
        x+=1
```

This is the loop that fills the first column with zeros.

```
x = 0
    while x<total_rows:
        print(x)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,x, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
        x+=1
```

And this is the loop that fills the second column with zeros.

```
x = 0
    while x<total_rows:
        print(x)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1,x, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
        x+=1
```

For other details that you may need when you are solving my problems here is the whole code. (I have no file sharing platforms available right now. Please accept my apologies for sharing the whole code in text.)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'database.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
import os
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

total_rows = 20

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(551, 602)

        #Layout

    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.widget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 70))
    self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
    self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label.setStyleSheet("color: white;\nfont-size: 36px;")
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(337, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
    self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.widget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #777;")
    self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_2)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.widget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_2)
    self.widget_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #556;")
    self.widget_3.setObjectName("widget_3")
    self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_3)
    self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.verticalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
    self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
    self.widget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_3)
    self.widget_5.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;")
    self.widget_5.setObjectName("widget_5")
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget_5)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")

    #TableWidget

    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget_5)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.tableWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #eee;")
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(total_rows)
    x = 0
    while x<total_rows:
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(x, item)
        x+=1
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    #CalendarWidget

    self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.widget_5)
    self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet("color:black;")
    self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.widget_5)
    self.widget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_3)
    self.widget_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
    self.widget_4.setObjectName("widget_4")
    self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget_4)
    self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
    self.widget_8 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_4)
    self.widget_8.setObjectName("widget_8")
    self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.widget_8)
    self.widget_9 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_4)
    self.widget_9.setObjectName("widget_9")
    self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget_9)
    self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
    spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem1)

    #PushButton

    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_9)
    self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;\ncolor: white;")
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem2)
    self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.widget_9)
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.widget_4)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget_3)
    self.verticalWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.widget_2)
    self.verticalWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
    self.verticalWidget.setObjectName("verticalWidget")
    self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalWidget)
    self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
    self.widget_7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.verticalWidget)
    self.widget_7.setObjectName("widget_7")
    self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget_7)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")

    #ListWidget

    self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.widget_7)
    self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color:#eee;")
    self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")

    #Get files and insert into list widget

    files = os.listdir("files")
    for index, value in enumerate(files):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(value)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)


    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.listWidget)

    spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3)
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.widget_7)
    self.widget_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.verticalWidget)
    self.widget_6.setObjectName("widget_6")
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget_6)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
    spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem4)

    #PushButton2

    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_6)
    self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;\ncolor:white;")
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

    spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem5)
    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.widget_6)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.verticalWidget)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget_2)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def save_file(self):

    #Takvim değerini al
    current_date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
    current_date_text = current_date.toPyDate().strftime("%d%b%y")

    #Table'daki değerleri al
    allRows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()

    #Pandas table için listeleri oluştur
    headers = []
    items = []
    for row in range(0,allRows):
        print(row)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(row,1).text()
        items.append(item)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(row,0).text()
        headers.append(item)

    #dataset oluştur
    data_set = list(zip(headers,items))

    #dataframe oluştur
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data = data_set)

    #csv dosyası oluştur
    data_frame.to_csv("files/" + current_date_text + ".csv", index = False)

    #listview güncelle
    files = os.listdir("files")
    print(files)
    for index, value in enumerate(files):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(value)
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = self.listWidget.item(index)
        item.setText(value)

def open_file(self):
    #dosya ismini al
    selected_file = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()

    #csv dosyasını aç dataframe oluştur
    data_frame = pd.read_csv("files/" + selected_file)
    items = data_frame["0"].values.tolist()
    items = data_frame["1"].values.tolist()
    print(items)

    for row in range(0,total_rows):
        header = row
        item = self.tableWidget.setItem(0,row, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[row])))

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

    #Set TableWidget

    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Defter"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Isim"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Miktar"))
    x = 0
    while x<total_rows:
        print(x)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0,x, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
        x+=1

    x = 0
    while x<total_rows:
        print(x)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1,x, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
        x+=1
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Kaydet"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.save_file)
    __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
    self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
    files = os.listdir("files")
    for index, value in enumerate(files):
        item = self.listWidget.item(index)
        item.setText(value)
    self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dosyayı aç"))
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.open_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I put the print statements if my loops were just wrong. I checked and all loops run 20 times (As the x values reach 19 everytime).

Edit: It seems like double-digits are the problem.But this syntax is surely true according to the documentation.

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(1,10, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed rows with columns

```
# ...
        x = 0
        while x < total_rows:
# ---            self.tableWidget.setItem(0, x, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0")) 
            self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))     # +++
            x += 1

        x = 0
        while x<total_rows:
# ---           self.tableWidget.setItem(1,x, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0"))     # +++
            x += 1

# ...
```

[image]